# Determining if object is of typing.Literal type

Tags: python, type-hinting, literals, python-typing, typing

I need to check if object is descendant of typing.Literal, I have annotation like this:

```
GameState: Literal['start', 'stop']
```

And I need to check `GameState` annotation type:

```
def parse_values(ann)
   if isinstance(ann, str):
       # do sth
   if isinstance(ann, int):
       # do sth
   if isinstance(ann, Literal):
       # do sth
```

But it causes error, so I swapped the last one to:

```
if type(ann) == Literal:
   # do sth
```

But it never returns True, so anyone knows a workaround for this?

Comment: If you do `type(Literal['start', 'stop'])`, you can see it's `<class 'typing._LiteralGenericAlias'>` - that _doesn't_ create an instance of `Literal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should compare with `<class 'typing._LiteralGenericAlias'>` instead:

```
from typing import _LiteralGenericAlias
if type(GameState) == _LiteralGenericAlias:
     #do something
```

Comment: `_LiteralGenericAlias` isn't defined in `__all__` which makes sense since it's protected - Indicated by its underscore prefix. Generally you want to avoid using protected objects

Answer (score 6):

`typing.get_origin()` returns `Literal` for Literal descendants, so what I needed is basically

```
if get_origin(GameState) == Literal:
    # do sth
```

Comment: _Literal descendants_ sounds a bit misleading, since `Literal` cannot be subclassed. `GameState` is of type `_LiteralGenericAlias` which has a `self.__origin__` member and this is actually what is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

[`typing.get_origin(tp)`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin) is the proper way

It was implemented in *Python 3.8* (Same as [`typing.Literal`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#typing.Literal))

The docstring is thoroughly instructive:

```py
def get_origin(tp):
    """Get the unsubscripted version of a type.

    This supports generic types, Callable, Tuple, Union, Literal, Final, ClassVar
    and Annotated. Return None for unsupported types. Examples::

        get_origin(Literal[42]) is Literal
        get_origin(int) is None
        get_origin(ClassVar[int]) is ClassVar
        get_origin(Generic) is Generic
        get_origin(Generic[T]) is Generic
        get_origin(Union[T, int]) is Union
        get_origin(List[Tuple[T, T]][int]) == list
    """
```

In your use case it would be:

```py
from typing import Literal, get_origin

def parse_values(ann):
    if isinstance(ann, str):
        return "str"
    elif isinstance(ann, int):
        return "int"
    elif get_origin(ann) is Literal:
        return "Literal"

assert parse_values("foo") == "str"
assert parse_values(5) == "int"
assert parse_values(Literal["bar", 6]) == "Literal"
```